# List customers that has order in the exact following order

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 1 table transaction

here the table transaction

| order_id | Customer_id | fruit_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | aaa | Strawberry |
| 0002 | bbb | apple |
| 0003 | aaa | apple |
| 0004 | aaa | apple |
| 0005 | ccc | strawberry |
| 0006 | aaa | mango |
| 0007 | ccc | strawberry |
| 0008 | ccc | apple |
| 0009 | aaa | mango |
| 0010 | ccc | mango |
| 0011 | ccc | apple |

how can i write query to get List customers that has transactions in the exact following order of fruit: Strawberry, apple, then Mango ?
(If customer have transactions in the same fruit multiple times in sequential order then it counts as one for example: ​Strawberry, apple, apple, mango, apple will be Strawberry, apple, mango, apple.)
anyone can help ?
Thank you

Comment: What would the end result look like after that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to keep only those rows where the fruit changes.  Then use `group_concat()` and `like`:

```
select customer_id
from (select t.*,
             lag(fruit_order) over (partition by customer_id order by order_id) as prev_fruit_order
      from t
     ) t
where not prev_fruit_order <=> fruit_order
group by customer_id
having group_concat(fruit_order order by order_id) like 'strawberry,apple,mango')
```